# The program accepts only letters and prints them backwards

Tags: c

I want the program to accept only upper and lower case letters, and if the user enters any numbers or symbols other than upper and lower case letters, the system will stop accepting characters and output the result backwards. I am use isalpha() on my code.
Here is my code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>
int main(void) {
    char users_enter[21]; // set an character variables that include 21 characters
    int str_length = 0; // set the length of string is 0
    printf("Please print the string: \n");
    scanf("%20s",users_enter); // accept character
    for(int index = 0; index < 20; index++) { // set the index of elements of string is 0
         if(isalpha(users_enter[index]) == 0) { // is character is num will return 0
             str_length = strlen(users_enter); // find the length of current string
             break; // stop loop
         }
    }
    for(int len = str_length-1; len >= 0; len--) {
         printf("%c",users_enter[len]); // print
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
 }
```

The test result is :
Please print the string:
str5y

y5rts

my program did not stop when I enter 5.

The expected result should be rts.

How to modify my code?

Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by `find the length of current string`? This will get the length of the whole string the output you are getting is expected.

Comment: @alex01011 I mean that i can use strlen to get the length of users entered.

Comment: I believe that you want to get the length of the string up to that character.

Comment: Also, do you only have to print if you have bad input?

Comment: @alex01011 Exactly.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of getting the length of the whole string, save the current index.

```c
         if(isalpha(users_enter[index]) == 0) { // is character is num will return 0
             str_length = index; // find the length of current string
             break; // stop loop
         }
```

This way when you find an *undesired character*, you will have the length of the string just before that character.

You could also get input character by character and stop when you encounter a number.

**Sidenote:**

Check the return value of `scanf()`, so that you can exit if you encounter a conversion error while getting input.